# notepad++ run selected code in python console seamlessly

Tags: python, r, notepad++, ipython

I often use R to analyze data, and really enjoy Notepad++ along with NppToR. Especially, NppToR enables to run a part of code without much hassle. I just highlight a snippet of R code to run and press F8. Then the code magically runs in R console.

Now, I am required to use python to analyze data. I know that ipython is great to work interactively, but it is always very annoying to copy a snippet of python code and manually paste that into ipython console. Also, indentation is often mixed and thus the entire lines are failed to run. Note that I want to run 'selected' lines of codes, not the entire file.

So I am looking for a program/plugin/macro similar to NppToR, but working with python/ipython console. I have searched the web, but couldn't find such one. Some plugins are nice, but not exactly what I want. For example, Python Script enables extending Notepad++ itself, but not outside. Various other 'Run' extensions enables the entire file to be run in python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [customize the editor IPython uses for the `edit` command](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/config/editors.html?highlight=editor), and configure IPython to use Notepad++. IPython 0.11 creates a `.ipython/profile_default` folder in your user folder (in my case `C:/Users/zk/.ipython/profile_default`). To configure IPython to use Notepad++ create `.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py` with the following:

```
c = get_config()
# use DOS style path, C:/PROGRA~2 on my 64-bit system points to C:/Program Files (x86)
c.TerminalInteractiveShell.editor = 'C:\PROGRA~2\NOTEPA~1\NOTEPA~1.exe'
# set editor for Qt Console, if you wish to use that
c.IPythonWidget.editor = 'C:\PROGRA~2\NOTEPA~1\NOTEPA~1.exe'
```

You can then start up IPython and use the `edit` command to run Notepad++ from IPython, saving and closing Notepad++ will execute the file in IPython.

If you don't mind installing [PyQt4](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/download) and [pyzmq](https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/downloads) (and I believe [pygments](http://pygments.org/download/), at least for [IPython 0.12-dev](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/downloads)), IPython's [Qt console](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/qtconsole.html) works really well (frankly the nicest interactive environment you can get for Python). You can paste directly into IPython and it'll adjust indentation for you (shifting over padded code).

Comment: Does this allow one to run highlighted selections of code only, rather than entire files?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried that, but it does not solve the problem. It surely enables to edit some code in Notepad++. Rather, I have already a bunch of code in Notepad++. I want to selectively run a certain part of the file easily in python console without manually copy/paste.

Comment: If you use `edit`, it will pop open a blank file. You can paste code into this file, save/close, and it'll execute in IPython. It's a slightly different workflow, but if you give it a shot you might find it useful. Using IPython has a lot of other advantages as well.

Comment: There is also a `paste` magic command which would let you just select chunks of code and hit copy, and paste directly into the editor smoothly, but it doesn't seem to work on Windows with my version if IPython.